# Python Getting JSON Array Using Filter from Dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that I read using json.load.

My object then is a dict called `data` that has a list called `units` that then lists a load of `dict`.

I wish to pull the `dict` out that has a `name = "X"`.

I tried using the following code:

```
async def get_unit(message):

    try:
        msg = message.content

        f = open('resources/units.json')

        data = json.load(f)

        d = next((item for item in data if item["name"] == "2K12 KUB"), None)

        #print(msg[msg.index('!gu') + len('!gu') + 1:])
        await message.channel.send('GU Command Sent!')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

However it returns an error `string indices must be integers`

Any assistance would be appeciated.